# .NET auto-instrumentation does not work when upgrading from 1.0.2-rc to 1.0.0

Tags: open-telemetry, open-telemetry-collector

NET applications deployed on Kubernetes using Opentelemetry-Operator to configure the architecture to obtain traces of .NET applications deployed on Kubernetes.

After upgrading the version of Opentelemetry-Operator from 0.83.0 to 0.92.0, traces are no longer being sent to the collector.

After verification, we assume that this is due to the upgrade of the dotnet-instrumentation version from 1.0.0-rc2 to 1.0.0.

We also performed a fresh installation of Opentelemetry-Operator at 0.92.0 and confirmed that both traces and metrics are not sent to the Collector in the same way.

```
apiVersion: opentelemetry.io/v1alpha1
kind: Instrumentation
metadata:
  name: simplest-instrumentation
spec:
  exporter:
    endpoint: http://simplest-collector.opentelemetry.svc.cluster.local:4318
  propagators:
    - tracecontext
    - baggage
  sampler:
    type: parentbased_traceidratio
    argument: "1"
```

```
apiVersion: opentelemetry.io/v1alpha1
kind: OpenTelemetryCollector
metadata:
  name: simplest
  namespace: opentelemetry
spec:
  config: |
    receivers:
      otlp:
        protocols:
          grpc:
            endpoint: 0.0.0.0:4317
          http:
            endpoint: 0.0.0.0:4318
    processors:
      memory_limiter:
        check_interval: 1s
        limit_percentage: 75
        spike_limit_percentage: 15
      batch:
        send_batch_size: 10000
        timeout: 10s

    exporters:
      # NOTE: Prior to v0.86.0 use `logging` instead of `debug`.
      debug:

    service:
      pipelines:
        traces:
          receivers: [otlp]
          processors: [memory_limiter, batch]
          exporters: [debug]
        metrics:
          receivers: [otlp]
          processors: [memory_limiter, batch]
          exporters: [debug]
        logs:
          receivers: [otlp]
          processors: [memory_limiter, batch]
          exporters: [debug]
```

I have checked all the [Troublehooting](https://opentelemetry.io/docs/kubernetes/operator/automatic/#troubleshooting) and confirmed that everything is fine, but please let me know if there is anything else I should check.